# Custom UserControl with ContentControl field

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a `UserControl` which acts as a wrapper for a `ContentControl`, which is simply a title to the `ContentControl`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Background="Green" Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Header}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Margin="12, 10, 0, 10" />
</Grid>
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Body}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And here's where I try to use the control:

```
<gbl:ListHeader Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding HasMovies, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"  Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.movie_list_header, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" >
                    <gbl:ListHeader.Body>
                        <ListBox  SelectionChanged="ListBoxContainerSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderListBoxItemStyle}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <gbl:MovieItemControl Header="{Binding MovieTitle}" Description="{Binding FormattedDescription}" Detail="{Binding FormattedDetail}" Opacity="{Binding IsSuppressed, Converter={StaticResource DimIfTrueConverter}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </gbl:ListHeader.Body>
```

The DataBinding to the list happens, however nothing displays in the control. I'm guessing that it's still there, but too small to see (undefined h/w).

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? The header shows fine, so the control appears to be working somewhat.

Edit:

Here's the code-behind for ListHeader:

```
public partial class ListHeader : UserControl
    {
        private readonly ListHeaderData _data = new ListHeaderData();
        public ListHeader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = _data;
        }

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(ListHeader), new PropertyMetadata("",HeaderPropertyChanged) );

        private static void HeaderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lh = d as ListHeader;
            if (lh != null)
                lh._data.Header = e.NewValue as string;
        }



        public object Body
        {
            get { return GetValue(BodyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BodyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Body.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Body", typeof(object), typeof(ListHeader), new PropertyMetadata(null, BodyPropertyChanged));

        private static void BodyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lh = d as ListHeader;
            if (lh != null)
                lh._data.Body = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    public class ListHeaderData : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ListHeaderData()
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                Header = "Custom Header Goes Here";
                Body = new Grid() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) };
            }
        }
        private string _header;
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set { _header = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Header"); }
        }

        private object _body;
        public object Body
        {
            get { return _body; }
            set { _body = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Body");}
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be useful to also have the code behind...

Comment: What are those property changed callbacks for? As i see it they serve no purpose besides setting the properties to the values **they already have** because it's a property changed callback, not a property changing callback. Also in the ViewModel you should check for equality and only raise property changed if there is no equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what i said in my comment you appear to bind to your DataContext in the UserControl declaration which is a Bad Thing and the problem of all this.

You appear to want to bind to the properties of the UserControl but you bind directly to the properties of the DataContext which is your ViewModel, hence setting the Body property on an instance in XAML does nothing as the property is sidestepped by the internal binding.

UserControls should for all i know do bindings like this:

```
<UserControl Name="control" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="Green" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=control}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" Margin="12, 10, 0, 10" />
        </Grid>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Body, ElementName=control}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

---

Get rid of those dependency property changed callbacks and change the property code in ViewModels to this format to make sure it changed:

```
private int _MyProperty = 0;
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (_MyProperty != value)
        {
            _MyProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. There's a lot of information in your post, but are you saying the DataContext of the user control should not be set, and the CodeBehind for ListHeader should have the properties instead?

Comment: @willmel: In many cases you want a UserControl to be able to bind to an inherited DataContext, if you set it inside the UserControl it will not be inherted. I do not know your use case so maybe this is fine but in many cases that may cause confusion as bindings on an instance that target the DataContext will target the one set internally which is invisible from the outside. There also is some dispute whether the view should be responisble for creation of the view model or the other way around i think, so it's all not set in stone. Not sure what you mean with your question about properties...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand.. Can you link to an example use of the idea you describe? This is how I've been doing UserControls so far, but if it's bad design, I would like to change it.

Comment: Removing the DataContext was actually the fix, thanks. I had a inner class that was actually having some issues itself (was passing an invalid value) which was causing it to not be rendered. It was not throwing an exception because it was multiple levels down the Binding stack I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @willmel: In data binding it is quite important to always be aware of DataContexts, that is why i recommend to not set it unless it is really necessary, Glad you could fix your problem after all.